# CURL doesn't return any output when reading URL

Tags: php, curl

I am reading a CSV file which contain URLs. I am trying to output the result of those URLs but facing strange issue.
I can't seem to understand why this code doesn't print variable $output when you try to print item which is on first line.

This is my CSV file containing two records:

```
www.serverfault.com
www.stackoverflow.com
```

This is my code

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("products.csv", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    while(!feof($myfile))
    {
        $myline = fgets($myfile);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myline);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if($myline == "www.serverfault.com")
        {
            echo $output;
        }
    }
?>
```

Notice in CSV file the first record is www.serverfault.com and it never prints the $output. If I move this record to second line then it prints $output but then it doesn't print $output for www.stackoverflow.com which is on first line now.

What's going on?

Comment: you're just assuming success. curl_exec returns boolean false on failure, which prints as a zero-length string. `if($output === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` and don't forget to check for whitespace (e.g. linebreaks) on your string. your $myline might actually be `www....com\n` or something.

Comment: You were absolutely right about both points. $output was false and it turns out there was a whitespace at the end of URL. Thanks. Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just assuming success. curl_exec returns boolean false on failure, which prints as a zero-length string.

Add this:

```
if($output === false) {
     die(curl_error($ch));

}
```

And don't forget to check for whitespace (e.g. linebreaks) on your string. Your `$myline` might actually be `www....com\n` or similar.